# Как правильно: украино-китайский форум или украинско-китайский форум?

Tags: лексика

Как написать правильно о мероприятии: украино-китайский форум или украинско-китайский форум?

Answer (score 1):

Если это "украинский и китайский" форум, то **украинско-китайский**.
"Украино-китайский" было бы возможно, если бы речь шла об "украинском Китае".

После вопроса в комментарии я попробую объясниться, хотя правила конкретного у меня нет, а ситуация мне казалась самоочевидной.

Я исхожу из того, что равные составляющие (не только в политике) должны быть представлены равными по способу образования конструкциями. К тому же вряд ли кто предложит "китае-украинский".

Что касается использования на новостных сайтах, то там надо смотреть, идет ли речь именно о прилагательных, или о чем еще. Скажем, тгипотетическое "Украино-румынский" географический регион (относящийся и к Украине, и к Румынии) не вызывает возражений. Но в отношении форума такое толкование сомнительно.

Comment: А есть ли правило? "Украино" звучит как сокращение. На новостных сайтах полно: https://www.google.com/search?q="украино"

Comment: @oleedd єто не сокращение, это другой словообразовательный суффикс. Впрочем, это здесь не так важно. Я исходил из того, что понятие в равной мере относящееся к "украинскому и китайскому" должно иметь равные способы образования. Другое дело если бы речь шла о гипотетическом понятии "Украина и Китай" или "украинец и китаец" и вот от него, от этого понятия образовывали бы прилагательное. Вряд ли такие вещи можно найти закрепленными в кодифицирующих источниках. Но на всякий случай - спрошу, может, найдут информированные люди подтверждение.

Comment: "понятие в равной мере относящееся" — согласен. Но и второй вариант хорошо звучит (без подвоха) и активно используется (747 тыс.). И вообще, вопрос очень интересный.

Comment: А вот что там и как звучит - это уже в другой раз. Я в ответе этой темы не касался.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***украинско-китайский форум***.

Именно  форма ***украинско-*** используется при образовании сложных прилагательных, и она указана в орфографическом словаре на сайте Грамота.ру, например: **украинско-русский**, а слова **украино**-русский там нет.

Объяснить это можно следующим образом. При образовании сложного прилагательного используется определенная основа слова. **Выбор при образовании таких сочетаний обычно отсутствует,** так как применяется наиболее **удобный в фонетическом плане вариант.**

Можно для сравнения взять сложное прилагательное **англо-русский**, для которого тоже характерна **единственная форма.** Основа прилагательного ***английско***-  для образования сложных прилагательных практически не используется. Например: русско-английские связи, а не английско-русские связи.

Comment: А когда же используется "украино-"?

Comment: @Sharon при общем правильном ответе, ві нагородили много лишнего. Англо-русский словарь связан с тем, что речь идет об английском, а не "британском" языке. А вот британо-китайские отношения встречаются, имхо, пореже британско-китайских. Аналогично франко-канадец - человек, но французско-канадский саммит. и проч.

Comment: Я только хотела сказать,  что полная основа английско- практически не встречается, она заменяется усеченной формой англо-.  Полагаю, что можно сделать такой вывод: при образовании сложных прилагательных от имен собственных используется только одна (закрепленная в языке) форма. Здесь не делается выбор между основой сущ. и прилагательного, но выбирается полная или усеченная форма. Также выбирается одна форма (украинско-, но не украино-) для сложных прилагательных, образованных от сущ. Украина